# Remote Desktop Manager for Windows XP

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

In my work environment I have to connect to 3 or 4 machines simultaneously via windows native remote desktop. I have to spend a lot of time in switching between the different client windows. Is there a better way to manage multiple simultaneous connections? I am looking for a freeware tool as I cannot convince my management to buy a tool just for my needs.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the way you are working?

Answer (score 1):

I use [RoyalTS](http://www.code4ward.net/main/) for just that situation.  The current version requires payment for a license but you can download an older version ([1.5.1](http://www.code4ward.net/main/RoyalTS/Download/StatisticandpreviousVersions.aspx)) that offers almost exactly the same functionality but is free.

That said, I ended up paying for the latest version as it was cheap as chips and had some nice additions.

Comment: This is off topic, but I'm not surprised that a product that is almost an anagram of royalties to require payment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try [**Terminals**](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals), it's a remote control tool that supports VNC, RDP, SSH, Telnet, ...
And it's free!

Answer (score 0):

What about [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)? Looks like they have a free edition on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

People at work seem to be zoning in on [Mremote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/)

> mRemote is a multi-tab, multi-protocol
>   remote connections mananger written
>   mainly in VB.NET and some bits in C#
>   2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Since VNC was mentioned, I want to mention [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) which is FOSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows 2003 Server, install the AdminPak.MSI file - this includes most if not all of the administrative tools available on the server.  One of them is "Remote Desktops" - which is an MMC console that lists all systems and can be connected to multiple systems at the same time.  There may be other apps (some of them could be recommended by others) but this is a free utility that can put all connections in a central location.

Answer (score 0):

personally i use royalTS, but there is another option if you don't want to install software on your PC. There is a remote desktops MMC snap-in which does the same thing.

- Start->run->mmc
- File->Add/Remove Snapin
- Click Add
- Select 'remote desktops', click add, click close
- Click OK

or altenatively

- start->run->tsmmc.msc
- Right click on 'remote desktops' in tree view on the left
- select add new connection
- you can figure the rest out from there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use RealVNC or TeamViewer

Answer (score 0):

I use sysinternals' desktops which create multiple local desktops on your PC. You can then open "remote machine desktops" in the different local desktops. This tool is multi-purpose and is not limited to manage remote-desktops only. You can have a couple of remote desktop open in local desktops and can have local app windows open in another local desktop.

The local desktops can be accessed with simple shortcuts like Alt-1, Alt-2 etc. and is configurable with Alt/Ctrl/Shift/Windows and [1-4] OR  [F1-F4].

You can get it from following link:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder in My Documents and put all my .rdp files in it.  Then I created a custom taskbar toolbar and pointed it at the folder with my rdps in it.  I put it all the way to the right by the clock and when the taskbar is locked, i just click on the little ">>" next to it, and it acts like a popup menu.